# Grails: GET request to /users/password return all resources instead of 404

Tags: grails

In my grails project I'm extending the default RestfulController. Here is the url mapping reports:

```
Controller: User
 |   GET    | /api/users                                                | Action: index                                                                                              |
 |   GET    | /api/users/create                                         | Action: create                                                                                             |
 |   POST   | /api/users                                                | Action: save                                                                                               |
 |   GET    | /api/users/${id}                                          | Action: show                                                                                               |
 |   GET    | /api/users/${id}/edit                                     | Action: edit                                                                                               |
 |   PUT    | /api/users/${id}                                          | Action: update                                                                                             |
 |  PATCH   | /api/users/${id}                                          | Action: patch                                                                                              |
 |  DELETE  | /api/users/${id}                                          | Action: delete
```

When I do a request GET /api/users/password I got a 200 response with all users instead of 404. How could I fix this?

Comment: I guess, It is matching your `|   GET    | /api/users/${id} `..It might have matched your password with id. Put a log in show method and see whether it is printing when you access ` GET /api/users/password`

Comment: Actually it is matching index method instead of show.

Comment: `Index method of show` I didn't understand.. :(